# Валидация в wpf до ввода пользователя

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, валидация

Использую prism и mvvm. Есть форма-редактор для создания и изменения сущности.
Для полей использую валидацию с применением IDataErrorInfo.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>

public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            var error = string.Empty;
            switch (propertyName)
            {                    
                case "Name":
                    return this.ValidateNameValue();                        
                    break;
            }
            return error;
        }
    }
```

Проблема в том, что при создании новой сущности все поля имеют значение по умолчанию (null/string.Empty). Вследствие этого при открытии формы для этих полей отображаются ошибки валидации. Как достичь того, что бы валидация запускалась только после ввода пользователем данных?

Если есть хоть одно невалидное поле, то кнопка "Submit" неактивна. Когда все поля стают валидны - кнопка активируется. Если пользователь ввел валидные данные, а потом отменил ввод форма стает невалидной и кнопка дисейблится.

Единственное, что нужно изменить - при создании новой сущности поля ввода не должны отображать шаблон ErrorTemplate.

Comment: А пустая строка — это правильное значение? Если юзер закроет форму с пустыми полями, это нормально?

Comment: Пустая строка невалидное значение. Изначально форма считается невалидной и кнопка "Submit" неактивна.

Comment: А если юзер нажмёт на OK, что произойдёт? Закроется невалидированая форма? Распишите подробнее нужное поведение.

Comment: И что должно произойти, если юзер начал редактирование поля, а потом удалил все символы?

Comment: Уточнил вопрос.

Comment: А вы где-нибудь храните результаты валидации? В принципе, вы можете на какой-нибудь OnClick устанавливать флажок, что нужно валидировать привязанное свойство.

Comment: У меня есть поле IsValid, при валидации каждое свойство обновляет его. К этому полю привязано свойство IsEnabled кнопки "Submit". Хочется применить подход без застраничного кода, т.е. без обработки событий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил данную задачу следующим образом.
В view model внес следующие модификации. Добавил поля:

```
private static readonly string[] RequiredProperties = {"Code", "Name"};
private readonly HashSet<string> invalidProperty = new HashSet<string>();
private bool isValid;
```

RequiredProperties использую для обновления привязок, что приводит к валидации.
invalidProperty содержит имена свойств с невалидными данными. Если для одного свойства есть несколько условий валидации, то для каждого из них нужно свое имя для коллекции invalidProperty. Добавил следующие методы и свойства:

```
public bool IsValid
    {
        get { return this.isValid; }
        set
        {
            this.isValid = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

public bool IsValidationEnabled { get; set; }

public void CheckValidityAllProperties()
    {            
        foreach (var property in RequiredProperties)
        {
            this.OnPropertyChanged(property);
        }
    }

public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            var error = string.Empty;
            switch (propertyName)
            {
                //error = "Some error"
            }
            return this.IsValidationEnabled ? error : string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

В обработчике события Loaded для формы устанавливаю IsValidationEnabled в true.
При нажатии на "Submit" запускается команда, которая проверяет IsValid. Если все данные валидны - сабмитим изменения, если данные не ввалидны - запускаем CheckValidityAllProperties, что бы подсветить невалидные поля. IsValid проверяем так:

```
this.IsValid = this.invalidProperty.Count == 0;
```